# Rstudio not generating .Rd files

Tags: documentation, rstudio, devtools, roxygen2, r-package

I had created an R package several months using Rstudio. All I had to was to select File->New Project ->New Directory ->R package and then add R files to the project after specifying project name. When I clicked "Create Project"  the R package structure with .Rd files would be generated. But for some reason this is not happening. The package structure is created but the man directory is empty and there are no .Rd files.

Note: When I did this earlier I did not include any of the roxygen annotations to generate the .Rd files. The .Rd files seemed to be generated based on the definition of the function itself.

I did install roxygen2 and devtools. What am I missing?

I could create .Rd files using prompt() with the name of the function, but earlier Rstudio  seemed to do all the work. Now it doesn't.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like RStudio does not support this feature any more. Got this mail from RStudio

"RStudio has indeed changed how it operates when creating a new package, and no longer creates .Rd skeletons for the R files / functions used when creating a package. "